# Скролл по кругу, при клике активный элемент скролить к началу блока

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

У меня есть скролл элементов[image: Как я могу при клике на элемент подсветить его и поставить под стрелочку? Скролл должен быть по кругу, элементов может быть больше]

Должно работать на дисплеях меньше 950 пикселей. Адаптивно.

Как я могу при клике на элемент подсветить его и поставить под стрелочку? Скролл должен быть по кругу, элементов может быть больше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно зациклить элементы, тогда вариант со скроллом не подойдет. Используйте Slick Slider или любой другой слайдер для этой задачи. Для перехода к нужному слайду можно использовать небольшую функцию. Я вынес ссылки за пределы блока, если требуется именно клик по элементу, оберните его ссылкой или функцию можно изменить, или добавьте абсолютное позиционирование ссылке. Вариантов масса.

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
$('.slider').on('wheel', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
}));
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>5</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если слайдер - это не тот случай и зацикливать прокрутку элементов не нужно, тогда вам нужна простейшая функция [.scrollLeft](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/).

Выглядит она как-то так:

```
$('.go-to-start').click(function(){
    $('.container').animate({
        scrollLeft: '0px',
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: А можно чтоб не переключатели были а скролом листать?

Comment: @Alinochka2579 внес изменения

Comment: Все так, но не по такой логике работает В начало, оно должно ставить первым элемент на котором нажали

Comment: @Alinochka2579 это еще проще

Comment: То что надо, спасибо